# ajax loading do not working with async:false

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make loading appear before making a request using ajax and even then the screen is only locked.

JS:

```
function showEstoque(productId) {
    if (url !== '' && url != '-1') {
        if (active) {
            hideEstoques(active);
        }
        var target = document.getElementById("productInfo" + productId);

        target.innerHTML = generateRows(productId);
        target.style.display = "block";
        active = productId;
    }
}

function hideEstoques(productId) {
    document.getElementById("productInfo" + productId).style.display = "none";
    active = null;
}

function generateRows(productId) {
    var rows = '';
    
    rows += generateRowsEstoque(productId);
    rows += generateRowsReserva(productId);
    
    return rows;
}

function generateRowsEstoque(productId) {
    var textContent = searchE(productId);
    var parse = JSON.parse(textContent);
    
    var data = parse.length ? parse[0].nothing : null;
    
    if (!data)
        return '<span>Nothing</span><table><tr><td>Nothing</td></tr></table>';

    var rows = '<span>Nothing</span> <table><thead> <tr> <th>Nothing</th></tr> </thead> <tbody>';

    for(var n=0; n < data.length; n++) {
        rows += '<tr>' +
            '<td>' + data[n].nothing + '</td>' +
            '</tr>';
    }
    rows += '</tbody> </table>';
    
    return rows;
}

function searchE(productId) {
    
    var view_data = "[]";
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url + "product/" + productId,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "text",
        async: false,
        success: function (response_data) {
            if (response_data == undefined){                
                view_data=0;
                return view_data;
            }
            view_data = response_data.replace(/\r\n/g, "");
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){         
            if(xhr.status == 404){              
                view_data=0;
            }else{               
                 view_data=0;
            }
        }
    });

    return view_data;
}

function generateRowsReserva(productId) {
    
    var textContent = searchEReserva(productId);
    var parse = JSON.parse(textContent);

    var data = parse.length ? parse : null;
    
    if (!data)
        return '<table class="info"><tr><td class="none">Nothing</td></tr></table>';
    
    var foo = data.filter(function(p) { return p.idType === 'foo' });
    var bar = data.filter(function(p) { return p.idType === 'bar' });
    
    var fooQtd = foo.length ? foo[0].nothing : 0;
    var barQtd = bar.length ? bar[0].nothing : 0;
    
    var rows = '<br/><table class="info"><thead> <tr class="labels"> <th>Nothing</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody>';
    rows += '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + fooQtd + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + barQtd + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
    rows += '</tbody> </table>';
    
    return rows;
}

function searchEReserva(productId) {

    var view_data = "[]";
    $j.ajax({
        url: "url" + productId,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "text",
        async: false,
        success: function (response_data) {
            if (response_data == undefined){                
                view_data=0;
                return view_data;
            }
            view_data = response_data.replace(/\r\n/g, "");
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){         
            if(xhr.status == 404){              
                view_data=0;
            }else{               
                 view_data=0;
            }
        }
    });

    return view_data;
}

function startLoading(productId) {

    var imgEstoqueProduto = document.getElementById("imgEstoqueProduto" + productId);
    if (imgEstoqueProduto) {
        imgEstoqueProduto.style.display = "";
    }
}

function stopLoading(productId) {
    var imgEstoqueProduto = document.getElementById("imgEstoqueProduto" + productId);
    if (imgEstoqueProduto) {
        imgEstoqueProduto.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<td
                        onclick="showEstoque(1);">
                        <div id="estoque_1" class="estoqueCor st-color_"/>">1</div>
<img id="imgEstoqueProduto"
                                style="vertical-align: middle; display: none;"
                                src="<c:url value="/images/ajaxLoader.gif"/>">
                        <div class="container-product-info">
                            <div onmouseout="hideEstoques(1);"
                                    class="productInfo"
                                    id="productInfo1"></div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
```

I tried to use the beforeSend, call before the ajax method starts, ajaxStart and even then it doesn't work and the screen just hangs. Could you help me please?
I called startLoading before everything and it still doesn't work
I removed async: false but, I need to wait for the data to be returned from the API

Comment: The data returned from your jQuery.ajax success handlers goes nowhere. You'd need to return a Promise then call resolve within the success handler with your actual return data.

Comment: something like that?
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                $.ajax({

Comment: Yes, that's right!